# Error that an imported component is undefined despite it is imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

i'm facing a very weird issue and i can't find a solution.
I'm rendering a component like this:

```
const Trans = () =>(
<div>
....
</div>)
export default Trans
```

Then i `import it as import Trans from './trans'`
And i use `connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Trans)` and an error
is showing that `You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received undefined`

Comment: Are you importing `react` into Trans?  Maybe that's the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably caused by a circular dependency.

The simplest example is

```
// moduleOne.js

import {something} from './moduleTwo';

export const somethingElse = something;

// moduleTwo.js

import {somethingElse} from './moduleOne';

export const something = somethingElse;
```

When `somethingElse` is declared in `moduleOne.js`, it goes looking for for `something` in `moduleTwo.js`.

But `moduleTwo` needs `somethingElse` from `moduleOne.js` to be declared first. `somethingElse` hasn't been declared yet because it's in moduleOne, which is waiting on moduleTwo, so it is `undefined`.

Your setup is probably way less dumb and more complicated than this but amounts to the same problem.

We use [circular-dependency-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin) to detect and fix these.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a component (or it looks like a component), don't forget to import `react` as well.

```
import React from 'react'

const Trans = () => 
  <div>
    ...
  </div>

export default Trans
```

Comment: Unfortunately i import React from 'react'

Comment: @user7334203 How are you importing `Trans`?  `import Trans from './trans' or `import it as import Trans from './trans'`

Comment: import Trans from './trans'

Answer (score -1):

if you are using connect method, its necessary to use "react-redux" package. Please check if you have imported that or not

Comment: import { connect } from 'react-redux'; I have imported it